# untie Windows 7 hardware locking

Tags: windows-7, boot

My work involves several high-capacity HDD's been plugged in and out depending on what video project I work on.

It's cumbersome to recover Windows 7 each time the operating system thinks that hardware configuration changed enough to suspect it having been moved to another system.

Windows is installed at system SDD, which is always in place, system partition resides at SDD, no page files on other non-system drives, no hibernation, but still when I shut it down to plug off two secondary drives - it simply stops loading and reboots every time until I either run Recovery Console or return back HDD which was in the computer while Windows was installed first time.

Is there any way to stop it from doing that?

Maybe I'm overlooking something and the reason is totally different, but I recall that similar work pattern never showed up problems with Windows XP, this behavior first appeared with Windows 7 for me.

Any clues anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're hokoing them directly into the PC, why not hook them up via an external interface instead (USB, eSata, Firewire, etc.)?  Windows should ID them as such, and not count them in it's hardware/activation check.

Another thing to try may be re-installing Windows (and re-activating) without any drives attached (aside from the OS's SSD).  That way the drive(s) can't be used in to calculate the signature used to determine hardware changes that require re-activation.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to contact Microsoft about an Enterprise license.  There's not much call for single Enterprise licenses, so you may get bounced around a bit before you reach a salesman, but I'm sure they will sell you one.